# I am having issue in creating Android platform build for my ionic project in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working over ionic 3.0 mobile app framework in Ubuntu 18.04
I have installed the jdk and Android studio in my system and also set the path for jdk and android_home
when I tried to build my project .apk file and execute this command i.e. sudo ionic cordova build Android then it gives me error I have attached the screenshots which shows what issues I faced while try to build apk file in Ubuntu 18.04

[image]
[image]

these are the issues :-

Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova. 
        cordova build android exited with exit code 1

Comment: Hey this is not recommended to run ionic cordova commands with sudo

Comment: [Please don't post your terminal content as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: hi Augustin R i am working over ubuntu platform that's why I used sudo

Comment: thanks suraj rao for this advise but I want solution for this problem

Comment: Android Studio project detected
Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Comment: [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
        information.

Comment: Could you add the output of ionic info ?